# Chronic for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for something like the Ruby Chronic library, but for Javascript. The main things I need to be able to do is parse natural time entry, not dates. For example:

```
Typing   Would Give
------   ----------
8a       08:00
8:30p    20:30
8:01 AM  08:01
21:22    21:22
noon     12:00
midnight 00:00
```

I could write it myself, but before I go off and tackle it, I wanted to know if there was something already available.

I'm using jQuery already, so if there's a plugin, that would be hoopy too.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this would be an awesome project to port to Javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of my previous answer recommending Date.js, I'd like to update my answer by recommending [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) instead. It's a stable project that is still under active development. In addition, it is far more feature-filled and has a superior API. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Date.JS](http://www.datejs.com/) is a wonderful JS library for working with dates and times.

Comment: Thanks! Is it reasonably stable? The website says it's alpha-1, the download is from 2007, though the VCS seems to have something from early 2008. What's best to use?

Comment: That's true, it does seem rather dated when you consider that. All in all, I've never had problems using it, and has always been pretty stable in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison support for Ruby Chronic.com date and time input formats.

Check this out 
http://www.datejs.com/test/ruby_chronic/index.html